# HTTP Post without form click that also sends the user to the posted url as if it was a form submission

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, http-post

Can you send a user to the url of a http post as if the user had clicked the submit button of a form.

Expected result is that the page does not populate a form with values that can be seen in page source.

I am using Classic ASP. This is the http post which posts the data but does not send the user on like it would if it was a normal form submission:

```
<%
strData = "some-key-value-pairs"
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.some-domain.com", false
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHttp.Send strData %>
```

I want the above to 'go to' the URL sending along the post data. Is this possible?

EDIT: the page is posting to an external domain. Data must be sent using the above method but want to know if this can be done without actually using a form which is populated client side. I dont want the form values to be readable in page source but i still need the page to continue to the url the "form values" were posted to - including the post values so that the external page receives the data just like a form post to then be able to display the result to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hidden form dynamically with javascript in the browser. As part of that routine, you could make an ajax call to get the form values. Then when the form values are retrieved, submit the form to the external page, which would display the result to the user. With this method the user could still see the form values if they watch the ajax calls, but they wouldn't be there in the view source.

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought about this but don't want to do that either. + 1 for alternative solution though. Assuming I cant do what I want using my method above? So there is no way to also redirect the page with the posted data instead of just posting the data and the page not redirecting?

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to use Server.Transfer for this, assuming you don't mind if the url in the address remains the same.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_transfer.asp

otherwise, you would need to do this with client side  javascript, but I don't think you're looking to go that route.

Comment: To provide further info the http post url is an external domain from the originating domain

Comment: can you use client side javascript here? can you explain why you you can't just use a submit button with a form that POSTS to the domain?

Comment: I dont want the user to be able to view the values of the form. An example would be the same reason you wouldnt want to send form values to paypal using html buttons. It is a layer of security to not allow the form values to be written to the page